# Getting claims in app with mod_auth_openidc

Tags: keycloak, mod-auth-openidc

I have a problem with an Open Id Connect app.
Server is keycloak, fully functional.
On the client side, I have a test app (iNetOrgPerson.html) that is declared in KC as webapp.home. That app is managed by apache and mod_auth_openidc.
Authentication works fine. 
However, I do not receive my claims neither as headers nor as environment variable.
Seems obvious that my my httpd config has something wrong, but I cannot see what.
Can someone help ?
Thxs in adv.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.webapp.home
    ServerAlias webapp.home
    DocumentRoot /var/www/webapp.home
    ErrorLog logs/webapp_home.error_log
    CustomLog logs/webapp_home.access_log combined


    OIDCCryptoPassphrase webapp_home
    OIDCScope "openid email"

    OIDCProviderMetadataURL http://zbook.home:8180/realms/testRealm/.well-known/openid-configuration
    OIDCClientID webapp.home
    OIDCClientSecret lx2ThK3H6fKlqPVD8LLuNNJuyForkrwu
    OIDCRedirectURI http://webapp.home/redirect_uri
    OIDCProviderTokenEndpointAuth client_secret_basic
    OIDCPassClaimsAs headers
    OIDCPassIDTokenAs claims
    OIDCPassUserInfoAs claims

    OIDCRemoteUserClaim email


    <Location />
        AuthType openid-connect
        Require valid-user
    DirectoryIndex iNetOrgPerson.html
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

And the headers are dumped with the following js script :

```
<script>  
 var x= "";  
 if(window.fetch)  
    fetch(location, {method:'HEAD'})
    .then(function(r) {
       r.headers.forEach(function(Value, Header) { x= x + Header + ": " + Value + "\n\n"; });
    })
    .then(function() {
       document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("pre")).textContent= x;  
    });  
 else    
   document.write("This does not work in your browser - no support for fetch API");  
</script>
```

Output of js is such as :

```
accept-ranges: bytes
    connection: Keep-Alive
    content-length: 3900
    content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    date: Mon, 01 Jan 2024 21:48:41 GMT
    etag: "f3c-60de9584a1702"  
    keep-alive: timeout=5, max=99  
    last-modified: Mon, 01 Jan 2024 21:48:40 GMT  
    server: Apache/2.4.58 (Fedora Linux) OpenSSL/3.0.9 mod_auth_gssapi/1.6.3 mod_wsgi/4.9.1 Python/3.11
```

Comment: how are you trying to show the values of the headers and/or environment variables in your target application, which seems to be a plain HTML file?

Comment: Added the js script and its output in my original message; thanks for your help...

Comment: Just found out. I was missing : Header set MyHeader %{REMOTE_USER}s. Now I received the user's eMail. But an explanation of what is this clause doing remains to be found...

Comment: you're displaying response headers in the browser... the point of the module in the apache server is to set request headers in the server environment

Comment: These headers are sent server -> client (browser), right ? This is exactly what I am looking for ! Just a question for my understanding : can you point me to some explanation for the trailing "s" ? Thanks again for your help !

Answer (score -1):

The mod_auth_openidc was missing the following stanza :

```
Header set MyHeader %{REMOTE_USER}s
```

Adding this, the configuration works.